# How to flash DM9000CEP V5 board

Tags: ethernet

I am really new to the world of building hardware and software electronic devices and need help with a situation.

First off let me give a brief background on what I know about electronics and software programming so the community gets a good idea on what to expect from my knowledgebase.

I know a little Java, C#, Python and AT commands, I have a good idea of I2C and how to program small things on Raspberry Pi's.

So now down to my question.

I ordered a DM9000CEP V5 board and want to setup the initial settings to enable the board to talk on my network. I have read through the documentation on the chipset but am not able to get my head wrapped around how to setup, for instance a serial connection with 9600 baud serial to program the EEPROM. Maybe I am missing something because I am not just yet use to thinking out of the box.

Please, can someone tell me which pins to use to initially setup the board?

I have attached the documentation for the chipset and pictures showing the pinouts on the GPIO side of the board.

Thanks in advance.

Ross Kopp

[image: DM9000B breakout board]

Here is the link to the DM9000B spec sheet:
http://www.davicom.com.tw/userfile/24247/DM9000B-DS-F03-04072014.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want to setup the initial settings to enable the board to talk on my network

You don't - that board can't do that *itself*. That board is just a basic breakout for the DM9000B chip.

> how to setup, for instance a serial connection with 9600 baud serial to program the EEPROM

You can't do that directly. The chip does not support a serial connection in that way.

> can someone tell me which pins to use to initially setup the board?

The [DM9000B](http://www.davicom.com.tw/userfile/24247/DM9000BEPProductBrief_v1.0.pdf) is a Ethernet-to-parallel interface chip. You need to connect a suitable MCU to that parallel interface you see in the photo, and program the MCU to send appropriate commands to that chip, before the board will do anything useful.

One application would be to use the DM9000B (and add appropriate software, including TCP/IP stack where needed, on the MCU), to add Ethernet connectivity to an MCU which didn't have that functionality built-in.

A more common way to add Ethernet + TCP/IP connectivity to a small MCU, is something like the [WIZnet W5100](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/product-item/w5100/) and related chips.

If you had intended that DM9000B board to do anything "standalone", then unfortunately that was the wrong choice. Sorry for the bad news, but hope that explains why you aren't finding the instructions which you were expecting.

Comment: hard but fair answer. thanks for the info... i will have to put this one in my back pocket and use it for something else in the future.